# Combine elements of dictionary given index in python

Tags: python

I've got to dictionaries with same length. And I've got two index. What I have to do is create a new dictionary like this:

- Elements from 0 to index1 from dictionary1
- Elements from index1 to index2 from dictionary2
- Elements from index2 to length from dictionary 1

I've tried this:

```
L = len(dic1)
result = {}
ini  = random.randint(0,L-1)
end  = random.randint(inici+1,L)
i = 0
while i < ini:
    key = dic1.keys()[i]
    vaue = dic1.get(key)
    result[key] = value
    i += 1

while i < end:
    key = dic2.keys()[i]
    vaue = dic2.get(key)
    result[key] = value
    i += 1

while i < L:
    key = dic1.keys()[i]
    vaue = dic1.get(key)
    result[key] = value
    i += 1

return result
```

But when I execute with several iterations something its going wrong because sometimes de length of result its not the same length as dic1 and dic2. Could u help me?

Lots of thanks !!

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered; what order did you expect `.keys()` to be in?

Comment: It's important the order? I just want to do that in the order of elements are in dic1 and dic2

Comment: Yes, the order is important. Depending on the insertion and deletion history of the dictionaries, the order of keys retured by `.keys()` can be totally different, even with the same current contents.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `OrderedDict` from `collections` to keep the keys ordered, but then you'd have to tweak the keys to keep them ordered as you want, which is not pretty.

you can also subclass dict, to create some kind of meta dict, that implements all the methods for a dict, while containing references to the three dicts and return the concatenation of the lists for the three dicts in the `keys()` method, something close to:

```
class MetaDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d1, d2, d3):
        self.d1 = d1
        self.d2 = d2
        self.d3 = d3

    def keys(self):
        return self.d1.keys() + self.d2.keys() + self.d3.keys()

    ...
```

of course you'll have to subclass `__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()`, `__iter__()`, `iteritems()` and all the others to make it behave like a dict. And then you'll have to make a bold choice on how to handle item setting... Of course, you can avoid the dict() subclass, and just create a class that behaves like a dict and define only the method you'll use afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

Dictionaries do not have a length, because they are not sequences. Accordingly there is no natural definition of a range of keys defined by the dict itself.

You could sort the keys in some way, perhaps.

Comment: But when I execute len(dic1) for example, it gives to me the number of elements in dictionary, isn't it?

Comment: Dictionaries **do** have length. The number of keys in the dictionary defines the length of the dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's still not a length.

Comment: It is most definitely a length. You are confusing ordering (which is arbitrary) and length here. Sets have length too, and no set order. I can remove up to `len(obj)` items from each type, and then they'd be empty. Tuples and lists have both, length *and* a set order.

Comment: @MartijnPieters To describe it as a length is an abuse of language, no matter how much you protest.

Comment: @Marcin: See the [collections ABCs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes); `Mapping` derives from `Sized`, among other items, which defines `__len__`; the hook to return the length.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just because it happens to use the same method hook does not mean it has a length. If there is no way to measure a distance between two elements, it is not a length, because length measures distance between two extremes. It is a size, notwithstanding the API. To say otherwise is to confuse our terms and our analysis.